# Problema con flexbox, position relative, absolute y height 100%

Tags: css, flexbox, position, height

tengo el siguiente maquetado de pruebas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        *{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        .cabecera{
            background: tomato;
        }
        .columnaiz{
            background: wheat;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .columnade{
            background: yellowgreen;
            flex-grow: 5;
        }
        .footer{
            background: yellow;
        }
        .container{
            position:absolute;
            background: turquoise;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .containerII{
            background: lightslategrey;
            display:flex;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .item1{
            background: white;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .item2{
            background: slategrey;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cabecera">CABECERA</div>
        <div class="containerII">
            <div class="columnaiz">COLUMNA IZQ</div>
            <div class="columnade">
                <div class="item1">ITEM</div>
                    <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
                    <div class="item1">ITEM</div>
                    <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
                    <!-- <div class="item1">ITEM</div>
                    <div class="item2">ITEM</div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

asi es como yo quiero que queden los contenedores COLUMNAIZ y COLUMNADE (conteniendo los items), que aunque los items no llenen la altura total del contenedor, el contenedor si ocupe el 100% de la altura del documento.
el caso es que si descomento los items ya se pasa la altura y hacen un overflow quedando el footer de manera incorrecta.
Eso lo soluciono cambiando en el contenedor principal Position:absolute; por Position:relative; por lo cual el footer se desplaza hacia abajo a medida que crecen los items.
El caso es que de esa forma cuando los items son menos que la altura el footer no queda pegado al margen inferior de la pantalla sino que lo hace a los items.
De seguro a de haber una forma de lograrlo con css (con js si se puede) pero llevo 2 dias sin encontrarla.

Comment: Tal vez no estoy entendiendo. El efecto de desbordamiento se puede controlar con doble anidación de modo que un contenedor intermedio tenga los scrollers y esté encajado en el exterior a 100%. Así, los elementos deslizables nunca producen efectos visuales no deseados. Y el exterior tiene el atributo de estilo overflow: hidden

Comment: Pero de esa forma el footer quedaria fijo (creo) y yo quiero que se desplace hacia abajo con los items. Eso lo consigo con absolute y height 100%, pero cuando hay menos items que la altura d pantalla el footer se sube hasta los items

Comment: Si, queda fijo, pero como el desplazamiento es interior siempre se abarca la altura de pantalla disponible. (que en cierta forma es elegante)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero yo necesito que el footer se desplace con los items porque asi lo requiere el diseño

Comment: Y, que debe pasar con el vacío a izquierda? La solución que ofrece @Franco luce adecuada.

Comment: El vacio a la izq va a tener opciones para filtrar los items q van a ser mostrados. Independientemente de los contenidos el contenedor verde derecho y el crema izquierdo deberian siempre estar al 100% de la pantalla mientras la cantidad d item no supere la altura. Seria una convinacion entre  absolute y relative. La solucion de franco ya la habia encontrado yo, pero cuando hay pocos items no funciona como deberia.  Crei que no me estaba dando cuenta, pero parece no es tan facil la solucion. Gracias igual por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendí tu explicación del por que el contenedor tiene position absolute, pero no es necesaria, descomente los items y funciona bien

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .cabecera {
        background: tomato;
      }
      .columnaiz {
        background: wheat;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      .columnade {
        background: yellowgreen;
        flex-grow: 5;
      }
      .footer {
        background: yellow;
      }
      .container {
        background: turquoise;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .containerII {
        background: lightslategrey;
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .item1 {
        background: white;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .item2 {
        background: slategrey;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cabecera">CABECERA</div>
      <div class="containerII">
        <div class="columnaiz">COLUMNA IZQ</div>
        <div class="columnade">
          <div class="item1">ITEM</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

La cabecera y el footer deben tener un tamaño fijo, luego ese tamaño fijo se suma para calcular la altura del contenedor de los ítems en este caso le di `20 px` al footer y a la cabecera por lo que la altura minima del contenedor quedaría `min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);` esta altura se usaría cuando la altura de los items no superen la altura del viewport, en que caso de que si la superen pasaria a usar la altura máxima `height: 100%;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .cabecera {
        height: 20px;
        background: tomato;
      }
      .columnaiz {
        background: wheat;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      .columnade {
        background: yellowgreen;
        flex-grow: 5;
      }
      .footer {
        height: 20px;
        background: yellow;
      }
      .container {
        background: turquoise;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .containerII {
        background: lightslategrey;
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
      }
      .item1 {
        background: white;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .item2 {
        background: slategrey;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cabecera">CABECERA</div>
      <div class="containerII">
        <div class="columnaiz">COLUMNA IZQ</div>
        <div class="columnade">
          <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

O también puedes agregarle un scroll al contenedor de los items cuando superen la altura del viewport de la siguiente manera:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    
        <style>
          * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
          }
    
          .cabecera {
            height: 20px;
            background: tomato;
          }
          .columnaiz {
            background: wheat;
            flex-grow: 1;
          }
          .columnade {
            background: yellowgreen;
            flex-grow: 5;
            overflow-y: scroll;
          }
          .footer {
            height: 20px;
            background: yellow;
          }
          .container {
            background: turquoise;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
          }
          .containerII {
            background: lightslategrey;
            display: flex;
            height: calc(100vh - 40px);
          }
          .item1 {
            background: white;
            height: 200px;
          }
          .item2 {
            background: slategrey;
            height: 200px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="cabecera">CABECERA</div>
          <div class="containerII">
            <div class="columnaiz">COLUMNA IZQ</div>
            <div class="columnade">
              <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
              <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
    
              <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
    
              <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
    
              <div class="item2">ITEM</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: pruebalo sin position absolute y sin descomentar los items

Comment: Es bastante difícil entenderte, leí la conversación de arriba y creo que ahora entiendo un poco mejor tu problema, edite la respuesta, pruébalo nuevamente

Comment: ok, ahi tienes los dos containers al 100% con un solo item. Esos items van a ser listas que vienen de una base de datos, si sobre tu codigo agrego por ejemplo 10 items para que se produzca un desborde veras que el footer no acompaña a los items como lo hace si se usa position:absolute en .container, por otro lado si se usa position:absolute si el footer acompaña a los items pero al haber solo un item (o ninguno, que es el caso antes de realizar una busqueda) el container verde y el cremita junto con el footer suben. Espero haberme explicado un poco mejor, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Ahora si, con un min-height se debería arreglar, vuelve a checkearlo y dime si te funciono, saludos

Comment: funciona a medias, ya que a pagina completa el footer produce scroll, si le doy 96vh queda bien pero en cuanto paso a otra medida (por ejemplo en modo responsive) vuelve a desbordarse el footer. No conocia vh como unidad de medida, soy nuevo en esto, apenas llevo 5 meses en este mundillo front-end. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Que raro, a mi el footer no me produce scroll, ni a pantalla completa ni en responsive, te produce scroll horizontal o vertical?

Comment: vertical. si ejecuto a pagina completa desde esta pagina ya produce scroll. tambien probe llevandolo a un html limpio y lo mismo

Comment: El scroll lo produce la pagina no el footer. el scroll de la pagina se puede solucionar solo si hay pocos items, si no habria que ponerle un scroll al contenedor de los items

Comment: si hay muchos items el scroll es lo esperado, pero con 1 item o ninguno tambien tengo scroll, imagino que ha de ser por algun tipo de descuento de cabecera y footer, no se, ya me esta poniendo paranoico, jaja...gracias por dedicarle tanto!!!

Comment: Volví a editarlo, ahora si creo que ya quedo.

Comment: si lo haces con height queda el footer fijo, pero si lo haces con min-height si funciona...aleluya!!!    No tenia idea de esta propiedad calc, yo lo estaba solucionando con javascript haciendo lo mismo con innerHeight, minHeight y restando el tamaño del footer y la cabecera, funcionaba pero queria que fuese con css.  Me largue a estudia js y estudie poco de css, no tenia lo del calc, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicacion, saludos!!!